# Sending string as int params in php

Tags: colors, fpdf

I'm using fpdf library to generate some pdf files with php. At this moment I'm lost, because i can't set the background color.

So, I have to use the `SetColor(int r, int g, int b)` [function](http://fpdf.org/en/doc/setfillcolor.htm) and I wish to send the values of RGB as a variable.

Using `SetColor($my_color)` in which `$my_color = "233, 155, 123"` is not the right choose. 
How can I send a color variable to SetFillColor function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use explode on $my_color and then convert each element to an integer.

```
$rgb = explode(', ', $my_color);
SetColor(intval($rgb[0]), intval($rgb[1]), intval($rgb[2]))
```